# Why does 'set' syntax not work for syntax highlighting in vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

On searching how to set syntax highlighting on in vim, I found [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-or-off-color-syntax-highlighting-in-vi-or-vim/) which says that vimrc should have the following line

```
syntax on
```

**Why is it not something like `set syntax on`?** Like we have `set nu`, `set ai` etc.

With `set syntax on`, I get this error

```
$ vi
  syntax=
Error detected while processing /home/lazer/.vimrc:
line   30:
E518: Unknown option: on
Hit ENTER or type command to continue
```

and with `set syntax`, I get this

```
$ vi
  syntax=
Hit ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 6):

It should be `syntax on` or `syntax off`.

`set syntax=something` is used to change the current syntax (c, perl, nasm, etc).

**UPDATE**: As @garyjohn pointed in comments, it's possible to turn it on/off for the current buffer and its corresponding filetype using `set syntax=ON` and `set syntax=OFF`.

Comment: You can also use `set syntax=OFF` to turn off syntax highlighting for the current buffer and `set syntax=ON` to enable syntax highlighting for the current buffer according to the current `filetype`.

Comment: @garyjohn: ohh, thanks! Updated accordingly.